# Floating Point Exception while running the program

Tags: c++, linux, openmp, floating-point-exceptions

I am trying to execute the program using OpenMP and see the time of execution but I keep getting Floating - point - exception.

Without the design.cpp file I won't be able to instantiate the DUT in the test bench. So included that file in other CPP.

I was able to run this file without OpenMP.

Any help on where I am implementing it wrong.

```
#include "systemc.h"
#include "design.cpp"
#include "omp.h"

int sc_main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    sc_signal < bool > clock;
    sc_signal < bool > reset;
    sc_signal < bool > enable;
    sc_signal < sc_uint < 4 > > counter_out;
    int i = 0;
    // Connect the DUT
    first_counter counter("COUNTER");
    counter.clock(clock);
    counter.reset(reset);
    counter.enable(enable);
    counter.counter_out(counter_out);

    sc_start(1, SC_NS);

    // Open VCD file
    sc_trace_file * wf = sc_create_vcd_trace_file("counter");
    // Dump the desired signals
    sc_trace(wf, clock, "clock");
    sc_trace(wf, reset, "reset");
    sc_trace(wf, enable, "enable");
    sc_trace(wf, counter_out, "count");

    // Initialize all variables
    reset = 0; // initial value of reset
    enable = 0; // initial value of enable
    #pragma omp parallel default (none) shared(i, reset, enable, clock, cout, wf, counter_out) 
    {
    # pragma omp for    // pragma
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            clock = 0;
            sc_start(1, SC_NS);
            clock = 1;
            sc_start(1, SC_NS);
        }
        reset = 1; // Assert the reset
        cout << "@" << sc_time_stamp() << " Asserting reset\n" << endl;
        # pragma omp for
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            clock = 0;
            sc_start(1, SC_NS);
            clock = 1;
            sc_start(1, SC_NS);
        }
        reset = 0; // De-assert the reset
        cout << "@" << sc_time_stamp() << " De-Asserting reset\n" << endl;

        # pragma omp for
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            clock = 0;
            sc_start(1, SC_NS);
            clock = 1;
            sc_start(1, SC_NS);
        }
        cout << "@" << sc_time_stamp() << " Asserting Enable\n" << endl;
        enable = 1; // Assert enable
        # pragma omp for
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            clock = 0;
            sc_start(1, SC_NS);
            clock = 1;
            sc_start(1, SC_NS);
        }
    }
    cout << "@" << sc_time_stamp() << " De-Asserting Enable\n" << endl;
    enable = 0; // De-assert enable

    cout << "@" << sc_time_stamp() << " Terminating simulation\n" << endl;
    sc_close_vcd_trace_file(wf);
    return 0; // Terminate simulation

}
```

//design.cpp

```
#include "systemc.h"

SC_MODULE(first_counter) {
    sc_in_clk clock; // Clock input of the design
    sc_in < bool > reset; // active high, synchronous Reset input
    sc_in < bool > enable; // Active high enable signal for counter
    sc_out < sc_uint < 4 > > counter_out; // 4 bit vector output of the 
    counter

    //------------Local Variables Here---------------------
    sc_uint < 4 > count;

    //------------Code Starts Here-------------------------
    // Below function implements actual counter logic
    void incr_count() {
        // At every rising edge of clock we check if reset is active
        // If active, we load the counter output with 4'b0000
        if (reset.read() == 1) {
            count = 0;
            counter_out.write(count);
            // If enable is active, then we increment the counter
        } else if (enable.read() == 1) {
            count = count + 1;
            counter_out.write(count);
            cout << "@" << sc_time_stamp() << " :: Incremented Counter " <<
                counter_out.read() << endl;
        }
    } // End of function incr_count

    // Constructor for the counter
    // Since this counter is a positive edge trigged one,
    // We trigger the below block with respect to positive
    // edge of the clock and also when ever reset changes state
    SC_CTOR(first_counter) {
        cout << "Executing new" << endl;
        SC_METHOD(incr_count);
        sensitive << reset;
        sensitive << clock.pos();
    } // End of Constructor

}; // End of Module counter
```

Comment: Why are you including `.cpp` file?

Comment: @Ruturaj : Without the design.cpp file I won't be able to instantiate the DUT in the test bench

Comment: @melpomene : sorry about that, updated the formatting.

Comment: @melpomene,  I used an online C++ code formatting tool and that messed up all the pragma omp for part. I updated that now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Scheff I used an online C++ code formatting tool and that messed up all the pragma omp for part. I updated that now. Sorry for the inconvenience.